# C++ try/catch exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, try-catch, c-strings

```
try {
    char message = "Error!";
    throw message;
}
```

Catch site.

```
catch (char* &e) {
court << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I want to display an error message but am required to do so with a C-string.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: In C++, `string`  (presumably `std::string`) is a distinct type from a C-string.

Comment: Your edit completely changed the question and invalidated the answer that you accepted. The code in the question now is nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not throwing the string or the array. Because of array-to-pointer decay you are throwing a pointer to the first element of the `message` array. You are catching that pointer just fine. Unfortunately during stack unwinding the array into which the pointer is pointing is destroyed since it is a local variable in the `if` block and your `catch` block is outside that `if` block. So you are then trying to dereference a dangling pointer in `cout << *e << endl;`, causing undefined behavior.

In theory you can do

```
const char* message = "Error! Invalid data for: Total Crew.";
throw message;
```

or

```
throw "Error! Invalid data for: Total Crew.";
```

to throw pointers to the string literals, which live until the end of the program, but that is really bad practice. You should instead write a class inherited from [`std::exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) or another standard library exception class like [`std::invalid_argument`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) and then throw an instance of your exception class. This way you can make `catch` clauses to handle specific types of exceptions, not just generic `char*` that could mean anything.

---

Also `cout << *e << endl;` would print only the first character of the string, even if there wasn't the lifetime issue. You probably meant `cout << e << endl;` instead.

---

> but am required to do so with a C-string.

There is no good reason for that, except as far as all string literals are C-style strings. The exception classes inherited from `std::exception` allow one to provide a string argument to store in the exception object via the constructor and to retrieve it with the `.what()` member function in the `catch` handler.

You could even use them directly, without inheriting your own exception class:

```
if (totalCrew <=0) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Error! Invalid data for: Total Crew.");
}

//...

catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
    cout << "Line: " << line << endl;
    return 0;
}
```